# meteor.js - onReady callback for multiple subscriptions

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm in a situation where I need to have the full data from several subscriptions before my app can run properly. In a jQuery/Backbone.js context I would do something like this :

```
var sub1 = Meteor.subscribe('foo'),
sub2 = Meteor.subscribe('bar');
$.when(sub1, sub2, function(){
    // do things
});
```

but I think this is not the Meteor way... (?) I could do something like this

```
Meteor.subscribe('foo', function(){
    Meteor.subscribe('bar', function(){
        // do things
    });
});
```

but this quickly gets messy. There is probably some kind of helper/pattern for doing this and I just don't know it...

NB - I am using the outstanding iron-router, and have also tried this :

```
this.route('baz', {
    // code ...
    'before' : [
        function(){
            this.subscribe('foo').wait();
        },
        function(){
            this.subscribe('bar').wait();
        }
     ],
     // more code ..
 });
```

but this doesn't seem to prevent downstream code from running, and so doesn't solve my problem...

Comment: This question inspired me to look into iron-router and I agree it is outstanding.  I don't know more about it than what I have been able to learn by watching the 18 minute update video, but have you tried the "waitOn" function?

Comment: the author says in the docs "Callin wait on a subscription handle doesn't actually block anything. It just adds the subscription handle to a list of handles we are reactively waiting on." I actually do want it to block the downstream code until these subscriptions have cleared

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the old way isn't working. This one does though. I'm using it for my callback bin at http://sa.gy

```
this.route('baz', {
    before: function(){
        this.subscribe('foo').wait();
        this.subscribe('bar').wait();
    }
});
```

Comment: If I do this, and then in 'data' I call Bar.find(), I'm often getting 'undefined'..., even though Bar is published on the server and contains documents

Comment: Tarang, wish i could give more than +1, you've been the only answer to my last few meteor questions !

Comment: This is a currently open issue on the iron-router Github page https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/265

Comment: This used to work a few weeks back im not sure what's happened. Try this instead, it works for me (Updated my answer)